# How would you write this model validation as a SQL constraint?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration, constraints

I have this validation in a Model for a `number` attribute, and I also want to add a database constraint. How would you do this? would you add an index or partial index to satisfy the scope and the if statements?

```rb
validates :number,
  numericality: { greater_than: 0 },
  uniqueness: { scope: :tenant_id },
  unless: state == 'pending',
  if: :number
```

I'm thinking about this migration to create the constraint but I'm not sure it is the best way

```rb
def change
    reversible do |dir| 
        dir.up do execute <<-SQL
            ALTER TABLE work_orders
            ADD CONSTRAINT number_uniqueness_constraint
            CHECK ( number IS NULL OR number NOT IN
                ( SELECT number
                    FROM work_orders
                    WHERE tenant_id = work_orders.tenant_id )
                )
        SQL
     end
    end
  end
```

Comment: I'd personally advise against doing this. By tightly coupling your Ruby validations to your SQL constraint, you increase the probability that you'll have to update business logic in two places. You (or another engineer unfamiliar to the code) may also run into a situation down the road where you do something like `record.save(validate: false)` and get a confusing SQL error.

Answer (score 0):

Business constraints should be defined both in the database as a hard constraint (if possible) as well as within Rails.

The advantage of having the constraint within your database is that this strictly ensures that your dataset is valid as the database will not allow to break the constraint. The disadvantage of this however is that if there is a query which tries to break the constraint, the error message will not be a great user experience.

Within Rails, you get great messages for each constraint and can handle errors very well. This works great for e.g format constraints (such as the numericality check). For uniqueness constraints however, there is the possibility for race conditions, as in parallel requests, the uniqueness check and later commit can overlap, resulting in a failed constraint.

Because of that, it is often a good idea to define constraints in both places. The Rails constraint will result in good error messages for most cases, the SQL constraint will strictly ensure valid data, even when there are races.

With that being said, your Rails constraint currently doesn't matych your Postgres constraint. You are missing the `unless` rule. For the uniqueness constraint, you may also use a much simpler [combined UNIQUE constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-UNIQUE-CONSTRAINTS) for the two columns, rather that writing your own sub-query, depending on how exactly you plan to resolve your edge-cases (i.e. the `unless` and `if` rules of your Rails validation).